# Fundamental class of products of spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $M$ be smooth oriented manifold where $M=X\times F$, $X$ and $F$ smooth oriented manifolds.
We note by $[M]$ the fundamental class of $M$. Is this equality true: $$[X\times F] = [X]\times [F]?$$

Comment: In principle yes, but you have to say what you mean by the right hand side.

Answer (score 4):

The Künneth theorem with real coefficients gives an isomorphism $$H_*(X\times F)\cong H_*(X)\otimes H_*(F).$$
Under this isomorphism, $\left[X\times F\right]$ corresponds to $\left[X\right]\otimes \left[F\right]$.

Answer (score 3):

This statement is proved in Propositions 80.10 and Proposition 80.11 of my lecture notes:
https://www.uni-regensburg.de/Fakultaeten/nat_Fak_I/friedl/papers/1a-uptodate.pdf
Getting the signs right was painful.

Comment: I don't know if the chapter numbering has changed since this answer was posted, but I believe the relevant proposition is Proposition 76.10 (as of today).

Comment: The link seems to be broken

Comment: I updated the reference, now it should work again.

Comment: The link was broken again for me too, but as of today this link works for me: https://www.uni-regensburg.de/Fakultaeten/nat_Fak_I/friedl/papers/1at-uptodate.pdf